# Where is the Xcode installer located?

Tags: mac, mac-appstore, xcode

When I browse the Mac App Store, the buy button of the Xcode app is shown as "installed" so that I can't buy it. But I can't find it in my Applications folder either.

How can I locate the app? Or how can I change the "installed" button to "buy" button?

Comment: By the tags, I guess the application in question is XCode (4?). It should be installed under /Developer, but I still have 3.2.5 there, personally, despite having bought version 4 from the App Store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try inspecting the output of

```
$ pkgutil --pkgs
```

to see if any of the names look like the package that claims to be installed, then

```
$ pkgutil --pkg-info thatpackage
```

to see where it was installed.  If it's not actually found there, you could try

```
$ sudo pkgutil --forget thatpackage
```

and see if the App Store will let you re-download; **but** at that point I'd probably contact App Store support first, as mucking with the package database might cause bigger problems (like, conceivably, forgetting that you ever bought the program — although I would hope Apple's programmers were smarter than that).

Comment: Thank you! I followed your instructions and solved the problem.

Answer (score 6):

FYI, I had a similar problem but eventually noticed (via spotlight search for 'xcode') that rather than installing the actual app, it had downloaded an app in /Applications called, "Install XCode" which was 4.58 GB.

Running that does the actual install of XCode 4.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already have a non-App Store version of the app installed?  When I installed Opera from the App Store, it replaced my existing version of Opera, which I had not installed in `Applications`.

You can locate the app by using Spotlight.  Click the magnifying glass in the top-right corner of your screen and type the name of the application in.  Click *"Show all"*, right-click on the application, and select *"Open enclosing folder"*.

Comment: The app file is located in a system folder so that it could not be found by Spotlight. But thanks anyway =)